# Microsoft Software Key Storage Provider for ECDH (Key Usage: keyAgreement) and for RSA encryption (Key Usage: keyEncipherment)

Tags: certificates, public-key-infrastructure, rsa, ecc

In the Windows Certificate Store, during a request creation, there are options given for the private key to be ECDH (Key Usage: keyAgreement) and for RSA for encryption only (Key Usage: keyEncipherment):

> *ECDH,Microsoft Software Key Storage Provider*
> *RSA,Microsoft Software Key Storage Provider*

What is the use of the ECDH KSP option? As far as I have seen, Public CAs only issue ECDSA certificates (and, even for S/MIME, they can't do encryption, unlike their RSA counterparts). I understand that an ECDH certificate could be used to show trust to a static ECC key. Has it ever, though, been seen to be issued by a Public CA?

As for RSA encryption only (keyEncipherment), haven't seen the in the wild. What are their uses and are they issued by Public CAs?

Moreover, according to the IETF standard, both ECDH (only keyAgreement, by design/default) and RSA encryption only (keyEncipherement), the key shouldn't be used to "sign" a CSR but, instead, the CA should: either 1) encrypt a challenge with the public key and the requester supplies the decrypted part, or 2) supply a challenge to the user and except a validly encrypted result. (same goes for the keyAgreement for ECDH). Does the Microsoft KSP do that? I presume it doesn't, because it also creates a valid certificate in the store "Certificate Enrollment Requests". Do Public CAs do that?